# Catch script that changes the data

Tags: sql, sql-server

we've got an annoying effect on one of our productive costumer environments. on a regular basis (2-3 times a week, but not always at the same time) a script, and i have no idea where that script comes from (maybe from a programm, maybe a script somewhere on the db-server), changes like 1,5 Millions Rows and updates 3 columns in one table.

Is there any possible way to catch and find out what script is responsible for the changes?

Thanks for four help and your ideas.

Comment: Please show some query/script,you can use sqlfiddle.

Comment: use SQL Trace to trace. Hopefully you can find the source of the query. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: install red gate sql search, search for the table/column names, maybe you'll find the script.

Comment: Maybe you could add an after update trigger that checks which columns were updated and how many rows, and if it matches, logs the connection info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try to:

**1) Install Red Gate SQL Search Addon for SQL Server**

(http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/)

This allows you to search anything. E.g. type in `UPDATE` in the Search Field and it will show you all scripts etc which has an `UPDATE` statement inside.

[image]

**2) Run SQL Profiler**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx

which allows you to trace SQL commands running on server and store them in log based on your definition. But it takes pretty much of server's resources so be aware of that.

**3) Write a Trigger**

Triggering logging of update statements.

---

I think the first option should be enough for you though. It is also the fastest way how to find such update statement assuming the update happens in some stored procedure or possibly any SQL Server Object.

Comment: will Red Gate SQL Search able to find add-hoc script or Dynamic Query from Application ?

Comment: i would think Profiler / Trace is a better option as it will definately capture the update query for all scenario and it does required any changes to the database or tables like creating trigger etc which will required proper testing in developemnt evnironment before rolling out.

Comment: As far as I know it searches only through SQL Server objects - stored procedures, tables, functions etc. Thus the answer is IMHO no, it can't. So if he is not able to search the cause of random updates via this addon, he most likely will need to use SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to capture the DML operations against the DB tables. One of the preferred approach is to build an Audit trial by writing the triggers at the DB level to capture all Insert/Update/Delete operations. There are several helpful URLs which would let you know how to do that.

In order to do the same at the DB level (as an Admin), follow the below URL,

http://www.sqlshack.com/creating-successful-auditing-strategy-sql-server-databases/

Feel free to drop a message for further inquiries.